# Running Curl Plivo SMS command in R

Tags: r, curl, rcurl, plivo

I am able to send the sms through terminal using below code.

```
curl -i --user AUTH_ID:AUTH_TOKEN \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"src": "1111111111","dst": "2222222222", "text": "Hi, text from Plivo"}' \
    https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/{auth_id}/Message/
```

How can I use Plivo to send same SMSs to same numbers in R.

Comment: _possibly by coding something in R_. what have you tried?

Comment: I don'y know how to use curl in R

Comment: there are 2 dozen posts in SO that show how to map command-line `curl` parameters into `RCurl` or `httr` calls. Which one of them did you read/try and what didn't work?